# Getting two jquery scripts to work together like they're supposed to

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the love of God I need help! I'm trying to get Caroufredsel and fancybox to work together like they do here:

http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/examples/carousel-lightbox-tooltip.php

...bu I can only get them working independently. I don't really know javascript so I'm failing hard :(

Here is where I've tried implementing it:

http://www.meanbeangames.com/

Only Caroufredsel is working at this point. Fancybox works if I remove all Caroufredsel code.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) thanks!

Comment: As above, please post your code! That way it will be helpful to anyone else who has a similar problem and stumbles over this thread.

Comment: how about you tell us _how_ it fails to work, i.e. error messages, description of the failure, etc?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to paste the code but it wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing `jQuery` library twice at line 15 and 189 (view source), this caused all reference to `fancybox` plugin added earlier to be lost (as `jQuery` variable is re-defined the second time you include `jQuery`). Remove the

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>`

at line 189 and you should be set.

Comment: Omg lol... thanks! I thought that this could possibly be a problem so I tried commenting out one of the lines... but I guess I wasn't commenting it out properly (was using Sublime text shortcut). I just trie deleting it and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**:

You are loading jQuery (the Javascript library) twice. Once in your `<head>` section (`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>`) and once in before your closing `</body>` tag (`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>`). Remove the last and update the first one to the most recent version of jQuery, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Second**:

It might be better to give better structure to your script: or you load all of them in your head, or all of them before the closing `</body>` tag. This way, you won't look over scripts that are somewhere you wouldn't expect them to be. Best practice is often said to include all scripts before the closing `</body>` tag. Don't forget to load jQuery *before* all the rest of your scripts! In your case it would look like this:

```
<footer>...</footer>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.carouFredSel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#foo2").carouFredSel({
        circular: true,
        infinite: false,
        auto: false,
        prev: {
            button: "#foo2_prev",
            key: "left"
        },
        next: {
            button: "#foo2_next",
            key: "right"
        },
        pagination: "#foo2_pag"
    });
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>
```